# Get the duration and resolution from a video stored in S3 using lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, mediainfo

I'm trying to get the duration and resolution of a video that I stored in S3 but I'm having some issues.

I tried it using mediaInfo and the process described in [Extracting Video Metadata using Lambda and Mediainfo | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/compute/extracting-video-metadata-using-lambda-and-mediainfo/), but I get an `access denied` error when the Lambda function fires. Later I tried some workarounds for that but it just keep me returning errors of many types. Finally I tried to use the [node-mediainfo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mediainfo) package, but it returns a time out error.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Post your code.